# "accounts and sync" has dissappeared, how can I fix this?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, settings, samsung-galaxy-tab

A few days ago I had a system update. Now under accounts my option "accounts and sync" have disappeared. Can't sync calenders. How can I fix this?

Comment: please specify android version 4.1.1 or 4.1.2?

Comment: And which device. You've tagged for two different devices.

Comment: 4.1.2 -I already checked what you stated to do.Calendars NOT syncing between galaxy tablet 2 10.1 and galaxy siii. They used to and REALLY need for business. How do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

**Settings** -> **Data Usage** -> Press **Menu Key** -> **Auto Sync Data**

In settings go to Accounts section-->Google and select your account and check what ever you want to sync